# Joining transactions on ID in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a transactions table with the fields :

```
TRAN_ID    DATE     ACCNT_ID    NAME      AMOUNT    TRAN_TYPE
```

For a given transaction which debits one customer's account and credits the other, I can have:

Customer 1

```
TRAN_ID    DATE     ACCNT_ID     NAME      AMOUNT    TRAN_TYPE
0000001   10/10/17     AA1     Joe Burns     50        Debit
```

Customer 2:

```
TRAN_ID    DATE     ACCNT_ID     NAME      AMOUNT    TRAN_TYPE
0000001   10/10/17     AA2     Mary Adams    50        Credit
```

Is there a way to do a join on this one table that presents the transaction ID, sender, receiver and amount?

Comment: So you know that you have to *do a join*. Did you try anything?

Comment: Provide an example from what you desire.

Comment: Redesign this table if you can. Do not keep (and repeat) informations about clients and transactions in one table. Please read about normalisation.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this, self joining the table where one for debit and other for credit,

```
SELECT R.NAME as RECIEVER,S.NAME as SENDER,R.AMOUNT as AMOUNT
FROM
        (Select * from
        Table
        where TRAN_TYPE='Debit') as R
        INNER JOIN
        (Select * from
        Table
        where TRAN_TYPE='Credit') as S
        on R.TRAN_ID=S.TRAN_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Self join, I presume:

```
SQL> with tran (tran_id, datum, accnt_id, name, amount, tran_type) as
  2    (select '001', date '2017-10-10', 'aa1', 'Joe Burns' , 50, 'Debit' from dual
  3     union all
  4     select '001', date '2017-10-10', 'aa2', 'Mary Adams', 50, 'Credit' from dual
  5    )
  6  -- self-join
  7  select c.tran_id, c.datum, c.name credit_name, d.name debit_name, c.amount
  8  from tran c join tran d on c.tran_id = d.tran_id
  9       and c.tran_type = 'Credit'
 10       and d.tran_type = 'Debit';

TRA DATUM    CREDIT_NAM DEBIT_NAME     AMOUNT
--- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
001 10.10.17 Mary Adams Joe Burns          50

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self-join:

```
select tr.tran_id, tr.name as receiver, ts.name as sender,
       tr.amount
from transactions tr join
     transactions ts
     on tr.tran_id = ts.tran_id and
        tr.tran_type = 'credit' and
        ts.tran_type = 'debit';
```

Note that this does not check that the `amount` and `date` columns are the same.  And, it only returns transactions that have both records.